# Is it possible to start Mono's in parallel and aggregate the result

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I know it is possible to chain Mono's, for ex,...

```
Mono<String> resultAMono = loadA();
Mono<String> resultBMono = resultA.flatMap(resultA -> loadB());
```

This will chain and resultBMono will run when resultAMono returns....

So my question is, is it possible to start 2 Mono's in parallel and when both returns continue with another Mono?

I think it will look something like this...

```
Mono<String> resultAMono = loadA();
Mono<String> resuktBMono = loadB();
Mono<Tuple2<Stirng, String> tupleMono = Mono.zip(resultAMono, resultBMono);
```

but I have no idea this will run in Parallel or what can I do this to run in parallel...

Thx for answers....

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**2 semantics, 1 way to make them run in parallel**

The two options I present below both need some additional tuning to make A and B `Mono` run in parallel: namely, each `Mono` should use `subscribeOn(Scheduler)` to get out of the common thread from where they're merged.

**If you only care about the completion of A and B**

Use `when` to listen for A and B completion and `then` to continue with a completely different `Mono`:

```
Mono.when(monoAwithSubscribeOn, monoBwithSubscribeOn)
    .then(Mono.just("A and B finished, I don't know their value"));
```

**If you care about A and B values**

Use `zip` + `map`/`flatMap` depending on what you want to do with the result.

```
Mono.zip(monoAwithSubscribeOn, monoBwithSubscribeOn)
    .map(tuple2 -> new Foo(tuple2.getT1(), tuple2.getT2(), "bar");
```

or

```
Mono.zip(monoAwithSubscribeOn, monoBwithSubscribeOn)
    .flatMap(tuple2 -> fetchMoreDataAsMono(tuple2.getT1(), tuple2.getT2()));
```

`then` will ignore the previous data, so it wouldn't make much sense to use `zip` before it.

**also, `zip` will result in an *empty* `Mono` if one of A or B is empty!**
Use `switchIfEmpty`/`defaultIfEmpty` to protect against that case.

Comment: ++ for the `subscribeOn(Scheduler)` hint!

Comment: For parallel execution `myMono.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());`

Comment: Why would you need to switch the scheduler? If both Monos do not block the thread they are started within ns/ms of each other and run in parallel afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Also if your publishers return the same generic type, then you can use `Flux.merge()` which subscribes to provided publishers eagerly.

From docs:

> Merge data from Publisher sequences contained in an array / vararg
> into an interleaved merged sequence. Unlike concat, sources are
> subscribed to eagerly.

If you don't care about results of publishers provided, you can use `then()` to continue with another Mono when the previous are completed:

```
Flux.merge(mono1, mono2)
        .then(anotherMono())
```