# Aggregating monos in Spring reactive

Tags: spring, mono, reactive

I am trying to aggregate the result of 5 service calls in Spring reactive. Each service call makes an external API call and gets a result.

Example:

```
Mono<A> = serviceCall1(...);
Mono<B> = serviceCall2(...);
Mono<C> = serviceCall3(...);
Mono<D> = serviceCall4(...);
Mono<E> = serviceCall5(...);
```

What I need to do is to make all these calls in parallel, aggregate the result into a Mono.  However, if any call fails, I should still be able to ensure that all calls complete. Some calls may fail, some may succeed.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to start Mono's in parallel and aggregate the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172582/is-it-possible-to-start-monos-in-parallel-and-aggregate-the-result)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I am planning to try with the zip approach. However, in this case, wouldn't merge be more meaningful to run them in parallel? I need to ensure that all calls run sync and finish and then I return a response to the caller synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is the **zip** operation in Mono. Just make sure you have the onErrorResume fallback in each of the above Monos. **Mono.zip** then would run when all the values are received of the existing Monos.

Answer (score 0):

You can you zip method of Mono where you can pass multiple Mono's. Please find the example below:

```
Mono<A> monoA = serviceCall1();
Mono<B> monoB = serviceCall2();
Mono<C> monoC = serviceCall3();

Mono.zip(monoA, monoB, monoC).flatMap(tuple -> {
    //here tuple will contain combined response of 3 Mono's which you have passed 
    //in zip method
    // tuple.getT1() will give you response of MonoA (first call)
    // tuple.getT2() will give you response of MonoB (second call)
    // tuple.getT3() will give you response of MonoC (third call)
    // infact you can create new object with response of above 3. 

});
```

Reference:
https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/reactor.core.publisher.Mono/zip