# Execute two Monos concurrently and take result of one

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Say I have two Monos, one which resolves to `Void`/empty and the other producing an `Integer`, how can I execute both in parallel, and continue on as a `Mono<Integer>`.
Specifically both of these Monos are results of `WebClient` requests. Only one of these produces a useful value, but both need to be successful to continue.

eg.

```
Mono<Void> a = sendSomeData();
Mono<Integer> b = getSomeNumber();

Mono<Integer> resultingStream = runConcurrentAndGetValue(a, b);
```

How would I write `runConcurrentAndGetValue(a,b)` ?

Initially I didn't need the value and was using `Mono.when(a,b)` and building off of the `Mono<Void>`. But now I need the value. I tried using `Mono.zip(a,b).map(Tuple2::getT2)` but then learned that `zip` will cancel `b` because `a` has a lower cardinality (0), and will end up with no item as a result.

I could use `Mono.when(a).then(b)` but I would really prefer to be able to execute these concurrently.  What is the right operator/composition to use in this case?

Edit:

One option I can think of is just a hack to emit an unused value like:

```
Mono.zip(a.then(Mono.just("placeholder")), b).map(Tuple2::getT2)
```

Comment: `zip` will return an empty mono if either of the monos passed in result in an empty mono. In your case `sendSomeData` always returns an empty mono causing the `map` to never be executed.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen yeah, that's what I meant by the 'lower cardinality' bit.

Comment: Partly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172582/is-it-possible-to-start-monos-in-parallel-and-aggregate-the-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reactor.core.publisher.Flux#merge(Publisher<? extends I>...)` method and take last element.

```
Mono<Integer> a = sendSomeData().then(Mono.empty);
Mono<Integer> b = getSomeNumber();


Mono<Integer> result = Flux.merge(a, b).last();
result.map(...);
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping that I could find a way to do this without casting, or changing `a`.  Also, I think I'd have to use `mergeSequential` to be sure of the order if I want to use `last()`.

Comment: If you are sure `a` is always empty, you shouldn't care about order. If you declare `a` as `Mono<Integer>`, you still can return empty Mono there. In that case you always get one-element Flux and you can use `last()` to wait both Monos completion